# SciTe and Python 3 - problems with configuration [UBUNTU]

Tags: configuration, python-3.x, eof, scite

I have big problem(s) with configuration of SciTE in context of Python 3. I do not know if details have any meaning, so:

[DETAILS]

1. I downloaded and executed gen_python_3_api.py.
2. I created folder "api" in usr/share/scite and copy-pasted there python3.api
3. I edited SciTEUser.properties as written in documentation of gen_python_3_api.py. It did not help a bit, so:
4. I used more general way found on website of SciTE. I edited python.properties and added a line:

   api.$(file.patterns.py)=$(SciteDefaultHome)\api\python.api.

   Still no effect.
5. I just edited another line of python.properties:

   if PLAT_GTK

   command.go.*.py=python3 -u "$(FileNameExt)"

   It finally worked (or I though so).

[/DETAILS]

Now I want to run simple Fibbonaci program that worked well with IDLE.

```
def Fib(n):
  a = 0                 
  b = 1                 
  FibL = []             
  for i in range (n):   
    FibL.append(a)     
    z = a               
    a = b               
    b = b+z             
  return FibL 

n = int(input("Number? "))
print(Fib(n))
```

And I get:

```
>python3 -u "test.py"

Number? Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test.py", line 38, in <module>

    n = int(input("Number? "))

EOFError: EOF when reading a line

>Exit code: 1
```

I am completely confused. Do somebody know why this things happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the generation of api is for editing only, not running your code.

Resolve the ambiguity with versions by adding full path to command lines (Hope, you do so in the 5th point of the question details)

The problem is in the line:

```
    n = int(input("Number? "))
```

Here you want input from user, i.e. interactive running, but editor runs commands inside its process and can output simply.

Change your code by adding variable instead of the input command

```
    n=5
```

or use parameters http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html#property-if

Good luck!